# How to create a function App to fetch data from ADX and SQL DWH and perfrom transfromation on theri data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer

I want to create a function app using JavaScript which will fetch the data from Azure data explorer and SQL DWH and perfrom some transformation to the the data and send the data to Blob file.

I tried to fetch data from ADX using Azurekusto data npm and my data looks like in the image below. I have parsed the JSON data and now I want to perfrom inner join on data between two different sources, that is Timeseries data from ADX table and payload data from DWH. I am new to JavaScript. Any suggestions on how to use my data from two sources and perfrom transformations like inner join to it

**This is how my code looks like**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

const KustoClient = require("azure-kusto-data").Client;
const KustoConnectionStringBuilder = require("azure-kusto-data").KustoConnectionStringBuilder;

const kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.withAzLoginIdentity(`https://clustername.kusto.azuresynapse.net`); // optionally also pass authorityId
const client = new KustoClient(kcsb);

const results = await client.execute("Database", "Table | limit 10");
//console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
//console.log(results.primaryResults[0].toString());

const obj1 = results.primaryResults[0].toString();
const obj2 = JSON.parse(obj1);
x = obj2.data;
console.log(x);
```

}

**This is how my result looks like :**

[JSON format of ADX table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr8oJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Use Azure Functions to develop Node.js serverless code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/develop-serverless-apps)
- [Azure Data Explorer Node SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/node/kusto-node-client-library)
- [Quickstart: Manage blobs with JavaScript v12 SDK in Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs?tabs=environment-variable-windows)

  ### +
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you also share some idea on How I can use the data from two differnt sources to perfrom inner join. i have stored the data in an array. Can we convert the data from array to table and perfrom some transfromations to it. Any suggestions would be very helpful as I am new to javascript.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not a javascript developer, however i guess you could use SQLite https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3. I would suggest open a new post for this with the relevant tagging